# Dataframe adding iterations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a strange one (for me at least, because im just a beginner). Anyway , I have a pandas dataframe made from an excel file.

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path_from_db, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1)
```

Straight forward, and it works. I then do some number crunching and add in a couple of columns in the excel file and update it using openpyxl in this case. after the number crunching i save the excel file using openpyxl.

```
wb.save(excel_file_path_from_db)
```

All the updated values are saved in the file. Perfect, its going well so far. Now i want to make a new dataframe from the last 12 columns i have inputted into the excel file. So I make a dataframe by reading the file again.

```
df_from_updated_excel = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path_from_db, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1)
```

Now I select the last 12 columns as my new dataframe

```
 df_last_12 = df_from_updated_excel[:, -12:]
```

I then try to print the "hello" column in my df_last_12 I do this by

```
print(df_last_12['hello'])
```

The problem is that there was a "hello" column before in my original dataframe and i inputed a new hello column in my new dataframe, so i am getting hello.1 hello.2 when i thought  should be getting just "hello" in my dataframe.
the funny thing is if i print `df_last_12` What i expected was that there would just be a "hello" column. but it seems to have these weird iterations. Any ideas how i set it up so that i not getting these iterations of hello?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic appears correct.  It must be the column names are not as you expect. What does `df_from_updated_excel.columns` return?  It must include *hello.1* and *hello.2*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNONPQRSTUVWXYZ")+["hello"], index=[i for i in range(5)])
df["hello"] = df.index
df = df.iloc[:,-12:]
print(df, "\n", df["hello"])
```

#### output

```
     P    Q    R    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z  hello
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      1
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      2
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      3
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      4 
 0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: hello, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, for some reason when do df_from_updated_excel.columns i get multiple hellos. there are hello column in the df, and i add  1 more column into the excel that have titles hello. but i set my datadrame to the last 12 rows which should only have 1 hello in it. so that's why i would only expect 1 hello and not hello.2 in the dataframe